# C++, OpenGL - Как нарисовать часть текстуры?

Tags: c++, opengl

Как нарисовать часть текстуры на языке OpenGL?

код:

```
glPushMatrix();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[id]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(texture->w, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(texture->w, texture->h);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(0, texture->h);
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPopMatrix();
```

Текстура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часть которую я хочу нарисовать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение:

```
texrX=double(x)/double(texture->w);
texrY=double(y)/double(texture->h);

texrWidth=(double(x)+double(width))/double(texture->w);       
texrHeight=(double(y)+double(height))/double(texture->h);

glPushMatrix();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, 0);
glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(-position.x, -position.y, 0);

glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[id]);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(255,255,255);
    glTexCoord2d(texrX, texrY); sprite.getPoint(0);
    glTexCoord2d(texrWidth, texrY); sprite.getPoint(1);
    glTexCoord2d(texrWidth, texrHeight); sprite.getPoint(2);
    glTexCoord2d(texrX, texrHeight); sprite.getPoint(3);
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 1):

В `glTexCoord2f` передавайте не `0`..`1` (это края текстуры), а, в вашем случае, `0`..`0,25`. Таким образом, будет выбираться нужный вам фрагмент текстуры.

Обратите внимание, текстура идет по координатам от 0 до 1, независимо от ее размера в пикселях и соотношения сторон. При выходе за диапазон 0..1, в зависимости от WRAP режима, она будет или повторяться, или отсекаться.

---

> А как мне нарисовать такую-же часть текстуры только в верхнем правом углу?

Ну пример:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(texture->w / 2.0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.25, 0); glVertex2f(texture->w, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.25, 0.25); glVertex2f(texture->w, texture->h);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0.25); glVertex2f(texture->w / 2.0, texture->h);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
    glTexCoord2f(0.75, 0); glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(texture->w / 2.0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0.25); glVertex2f(texture->w / 2.0, texture->h / 2.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.75, 0.25); glVertex2f(0, texture->h / 2.0);
glEnd();
```

Comment: А как мне нарисовать такую-же часть текстуры только в верхнем правом углу?

Comment: Точно так же как и первую часть, либо добавить ещё 4 вершины, по которым построится `QUAD`, либо в новом `glBegin`/`glEnd`.

Comment: Напишите код пожалуйста!

Comment: @RedBull посмотрите